# Batch File to read value of a specific property and use it as a variable

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch script to read the values of property which is passed as a argument to batch script during execution.

I have a Properties File (Input.properties) with below entries.

```
APP1_NAME=common1
APP1_PATH=path1\val\test
APP1_VERSION=1.0
APP2_NAME=common2
APP2_PATH=path2\val\test
APP2_VERSION=2.0
APP3_NAME=common3
APP3_PATH=path3\val\test
APP3_VERSION=3.0
```

I have a batch (Read.bat) script to which ${APP} an argument is passed with a value either of 3 APP1/APP2/APP3.  I am trying to read the value of a specific property based on the value passed and store it in a variable and use it for further. Let's say we pass APP1 to the Read.bat we should be able to read NAME, PATH and VERSION of APP1.

I tried below which works If i want to read a value by passing static property  but I am looking something works if a part of property name passed as variable value.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,* delims== " %%i in (Input.properties) do (
echo %APP1_NAME%
)
```

The expected one is if we pass APP2 as an argument to Read.bat
We should be able to read the value of APP2_NAME and store it in variable and read value of APP2_PATH and store it another variable for further use.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning a single variable in your code although you try to return one.

You could use the following code, which searches the file `Input.properties` for lines that begin with the string given as a command line argument followed by an underscore (`_`) and assigns all the respective matching variables:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

(
    for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('findstr /IBC:"%~1_" "Input.properties"') do (
        set "%%I=%%J"
    )
) || (>&2 echo No items found! & exit /B 1)
set "%~1_"

endlocal
exit /B
```

Note that the variables are no longer available after the `endlocal` command, so if you need the variables after the above code ran you need to remove the `setlocal` and `endlocal` lines.

Comment: Hi aschipfl  I have ran the script below is the output:
APP2_NAME=common2
APP2_PATH=path2\val\test
APP2_VERSION=2.0 . I am really looking to grab the APP2_NAME value not the showing as shown above.

Comment: If the variables still need to be present after my script ran you need to remove the `setlocal` and `endlocal` lines...

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different answer, first checking the passed argument for validity and not using setlocal:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\06\06\SO_56480912.cmd
@Echo off
Echo:%~1|findstr /ix "APP[1-3]" >Nul ||(Echo wrong arg %1 &Pause&exit /B 1)
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /I "^%~1_" input.properties') do set "%%A"
set %~1
```

---

```
> Q:\Test\2019\06\06\SO_56480912.cmd apP2
APP2_NAME=common2
APP2_PATH=path2\val\test
APP2_VERSION=2.0

> Q:\Test\2019\06\06\SO_56480912.cmd apP4
wrong arg apP4
```

Comment: Hi LotPings, I need to grab the value of APP2_NAME property into a variable and use it further not displaying the findstr output.

Comment: Well the last `Set %~1` just outputs the variables being set (and ready to use with `%APP2_NAME%`), the 1st findstr serves to check for valid arguments.